# ekko lightbox - Image in a modal without need of an a href wrapping it

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, tinymce-5

I am using ekko lightbox (http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/) + tinymce 5. I have img-fluid class so image is resized. My idea is now to use lightbox just to open it in a modal without need of wrapping it, because I don't know if it is simple to enable timymce to wrap img with a href and some extra attributes.

So how to popup image just by clicking on img tag that hold that image I ekko lightbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Done, I found it myself. So I just did this:

```
  $('img[data-toggle="lightbox"],img.thickbox').each(function(){
    if (!$(this).attr("data-remote")){
      $(this).attr("data-remote", $(this).attr("src")).css("cursor", "pointer");
    }
  });
```

and in tinymce configuration:

```
            image_class_list: [
              {
                title: 'None', value: ''}
              ,
              {
                title: 'Responsive image', value: 'img-fluid'
              }
              ,
              {
                title: 'Responsive image + modal', value: 'img-fluid thickbox'
              }
            ],
```